# Using a DLL with MS-MPI Program

Tags: c, dll, ms-mpi

I've got a program that I've been trying to parallelize with Microsoft MPI. The program is functioning well on its own, but I'm running into issues when I try to load a DLL.

When I try to load the DLL using the C "LoadLibrary" function, the function returns a null pointer, and the program stops executing.

Both the application and the DLL are written in C programming language. The application has been compiled using Visual Studio, with options turned on to link the program with MPI libraries as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/windowshpc/how-to-compile-and-run-a-simple-ms-mpi-program). The DLL is compiled using the MingW GCC compiler for Windows. The application and the program are both 64 bit.

Do I need to compile the DLL with MS-MPI libraries as well? Are there any other issues that could be causing this issue? The DLL and program sit in the same directory, and when I use the standard version of the program compiled with GCC, it has no problems loading the DLL.